# Robocopy max file size limit to be copied & alternative file copy tools to robocopy

Tags: .net, windows, copy, robocopy

I was going through documentation of robocopy and i find it interesting as command line robust copy operation tool. But I did not find information of maximum file size it can handle. Can anyone one has idea about it?

Also, is there any alternative tools available in market which can give competition in feature to Robocopy in windows OS?

Comment: It's bigger than 4GB so it's safe to assume that it is practically infinite.

Comment: There is no reason to think it has any file size limit, beyond that inherent to the Win32 API.

Comment: Do we have other alternative to robocopy which I can use it in C# .net program and has better copy functionality and having other features?

Answer (score 2):

To answer OP's question, I've copied giant ~100GB video files using robocopy with no issues.  If your network connection isn't the greatest /Z will be your friend and if what you're copying is all large files then /J will help performance a bit.  I suspect that any any file size limitations would come from the file system that you're using.

Chiming in to answer the replies regarding robocopying large numbers of small files, I've performed a lot of large robocopy jobs over the years.  The largest one was ~20 million small files and gave no unexpected issues.  I believe I finally hit the max number this week while attempting to robocopy a folder with 63,817,875 small files onto a separate volume.

I'm running Windows Server 2019 Standard (2061) with 8 cores & 8GB of RAM.  The exact command line was:

`robocopy "\\SourceShare$" "\\DestShare$" /COPY:DATO /Z /E /W:1 /R:1 /NP /MT:16 /LOG+:\\WindowsShare$\MyHomeDirectory\RobocopyLogs\BigCopy.log`

It would eventually use all available RAM and start throwing errors such as this in the robocopy log:

`robocopy ERROR 8 (0x00000008) Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.`

It would log Event ID 1000 in the Windows Application log, with text like this:

```
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.17763.475, time stamp: 0xf362c2f9
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x000000000000ae92
Faulting process id: 0x1504
Faulting application start time: 0x01d78a10dc030d96
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Robocopy.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 51c58e72-5c41-4262-8f32-eafcbcf476ee
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Sometimes when switching back to the RDP window and unlocking the session, the screen would be blank as if explorer.exe wasn't running.  Other times there would be an application popup that said, "System Error : Unknown Hard Error" and that was logged as Event ID 26 in the System Log:

```
Application popup: Robocopy.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
```

Since I was running this from a vm it was easy to expand the RAM to try to get it to complete, but it always memory leaked and crashed.  I also tried reducing the /MT threads, running /MIR instead of /COPY:DATO, and using DFS paths instead of $ shares, to no effect.  My workaround was to grab the folder list by opening a Command Prompt and running:

```
dir /ad /b "\\SourceShare$" > .\Desktop\BigCopy.txt
```

I then used that folder list to script a separate robocopy command for each folder using Excel.  Once I had the script just so, I was able to copy the concatenated commands and paste those into a command prompt window so that each folder was copied using a separate robocopy process.  Because I have several dedicated robocopy vm's, I pasted a few hundred lines into several boxes simultaneously to *really* take advantage of /MT and our powerful storage systems.

Answer (score 1):

Recently did a robocopy transfer of 5TB (8 million directories and 10 million files) in 52 hours. Robocopy is stable enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its not the size that is limited, I have copied TB sized VHDX data drives.  However, I have experienced a RoboCopy limit in the Number of Files to be copied.  We had a drive with an estimated  0.5 - 1.0 Million files (but very small) that made the Robocopy application hang and crash.  It apparently has to pre-scan the directory and at some number stops.  I have successfully used FastCopy ver 3.85 (Latest) in that situation. Its Free, and claims to be the Fastest copy/backup software on Windows.